# Naming convention of @FunctionalInterface

Tags: java, naming-conventions, functional-interface

By convention, types should be named by nouns, that's ok. However, `@FunctionalInterface` is a special type - object type that acts like function/method. In case of function I feel like it's more natural to choose a verb e.g. `decorate.apply(o)` instead of noun `decorator.apply(o)`. And there are also nouns expressing an activities e.g. `decoration.apply(o)`.

If I look at [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package all the functions are named by nouns: `Function`, `Operator`, `Consumer`, `Supplier`, ... Should I prefer **nouns**, **verbs** or **nouns expressing verbs**?

**UPDATE**

Sometimes, we can get little help with factory method returning an object/function:

```
// toList factory returning Collector instance
list.stream().filter(...).collect(toList());
```

Comment: Class names are nouns, method and function names are verbs - if you see something having noun name in spec - it means somewhere there's a class or an interface having such name. Whenever you have an object - it's identified by nouns, whenever you have a behavior - it's identified by verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@FunctionalInterface` can mark only types (classes, interfaces, annotations, enums).

To name a type you should use a noun, while for a method you need a verb.

> ### Classes
>
> Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive. Use whole words-avoid acronyms and abbreviations (unless the abbreviation is much more widely used than the long form, such as URL or HTML).
>
> ```
> class Raster; 
> class ImageSprite;
> ```
>
> ### **Methods**
>
> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.
>
> ```
> run(); 
> runFast(); 
> getBackground();
> ```
>
> <sup>[Naming Conventions, Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)</sup>

Here's an example of how I would define a functional interface.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Decorator {

    void decorate();

}
```

In code, it looks readable.

```
Decorator decorator = () -> {};
decorator.decorate();
```

---

My thoughts on "decorator vs decoration":

`"Decoration"` is more about describing the process/result, while `"Decorator"` is a mechanism/tool/means to start that process/to obtain that result.

If I saw the `Decoration` class in code, I would think about a collection of decoration stuff (like ornaments, paints, wallpapers) rather than a person who actually decorate.

If I saw `Decorator` or `Painter`, I would be expecting methods like `decorate()` or `paint()` because that's what they can/should do.

Compare `suppliance/supplier -> get()` and `consumption/consumer -> accept(t)`.